# Issue to bind more than one property into single element property

Tags: wpf, multibinding

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Content>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0},{1}">
                <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                <Binding Path="Height" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>                            
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Here i tried to bind the window's width and height into button content but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: StringFormat requires the target to be of type string.

Comment: what you wanna achive? i dont get it. if you use multibinding you should also use a multiconverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adrian suggested, you have to assign the result of a `StringFormat` binding to a text control.  Try this instead:

```
  <Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0},{1}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}"/>                            
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
<Button>
   <Button.Content>
          <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left">  
                <Run Text="{Binding ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                <Run Text=" | " />           
                <Run Text="{Binding ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
           </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

By using **Run** you can create whatever you want to display. and also can show on diffrent style on each **Run** for e.g. you can create bold effect on first run and other could be diffrent as like italic or something else.

Rether then using **Height** and **Width** properties of Window use **ActualHeight** and **ActualWidth** Properties which will provide you a actual values. there could be a chance that you will get NAN on Height and Width as they were not defined specifically.